# Catch Geolocation Error - Async Await

Tags: javascript, geolocation, async-await, ecmascript-2017

How can I catch the geolocation specific error to notify the user that they must have geolocation turned on?

The catch logs an error called **PositionError** as referenced here in the Mozilla docs "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionError".

*Note: my code does not catch the error, it simply displays:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: PositionError is not defined
```

**Code**

```
getCurrentLocation() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0
        });
    });
},
async inout() {
    try {
        let location = await this.getCurrentLocation();
        let response = await axios.post(API.URL, {});
    } catch (e) {
        if(e instanceof PositionError) {
            console.log('position error')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess PositionError is not known to the browser (but "anonymously" returned by getCUrrentPosition). You could instead check `Object.prototype.toString.call(error) === '[object PositionError]'`.

Comment: `async/await` is part of **ES2017**, not ES7.

Answer (score 8):

The `getCurrentPosition()` API was poorly designed, assuming users would test errors immediately in the callback, instead of passing them up.

Since `PositionError` has no public constructor, `window.PositionError` is not defined.

As Fabian mentions in comments, you can test for the error like this:

```
if (e.toString() == '[object PositionError]') {
  console.log('position error')
}
```

or use his version if you're calling any API likely to throw non-object errors (hopefully rare).

However, instead of littering your code, I recommend throwing a better error from your new async `getCurrentLocation()` API instead (use [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/aanv426x/) to get around SO code snippet sandbox):

```js
function getCurrentLocation(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, ({code, message}) =>
      reject(Object.assign(new Error(message), {name: "PositionError", code})),
      options);
    });
};
async function inout() {
  try {
    console.log(await this.getCurrentLocation({
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    }));
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.name == 'PositionError') {
      console.log(e.message + ". code = " + e.code);
    }
  }
}
inout().catch(e => console.log(e)); // User denied geolocation prompt. code = 1
```